# When having image in div change on hover, the image is cut off

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an image change when a user hovers over it, but the method I used seems to cut off the image, not showing all of it. How can I have it scale the image to the size I specify, rather than just making the div that size and cutting off the rest?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar-image" id="navbar-image-ID2Games">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navbar-image-ID2Games { 
    width: 5rem; 
    height: 5rem; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ou5cX4D.png); 
} 

#navbar-image-ID2Games:hover { 
    width: 5rem; 
    height: 5rem; 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Tx0SVZr.png) no-repeat; 
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/7a7ghfw4/

As you can see from the imgur url, the image is supposed to be a save icon, but it cuts off everything but the top left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "background-size: contain" to both of your css rules.

```
#navbar-image-ID2Games { 
    width: 5rem; 
    height: 5rem; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ou5cX4D.png);
    background-size: contain;
} 

#navbar-image-ID2Games:hover { 
    width: 5rem; 
    height: 5rem; 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Tx0SVZr.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#navbar-image-ID2Games { 
    width: 265px; 
    height: 265px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Ou5cX4D.png); 
} 

#navbar-image-ID2Games:hover { 
    width: 265px; 
    height: 265px; 
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/Tx0SVZr.png) no-repeat; 
}
```

I only changed the width and height for both classes